# Broken Packages List

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I've tried a lot of commands to fix my broken packages!
With no luck.
I only have 1 question.
How do I get the list of broken packages?
sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r
That command does not work!
Is there a new command for Ubuntu 20.04?

Update commands ran.
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$  sudo apt-get check
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
[sudo] password for cougarxr7:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aptitude
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ aptitude search "?broken

> ^C
> cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
> sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install steam
> sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> However the following packages replace it:
> steam-devices

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install discord
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "discord", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install discord"

E: Unable to locate package discord
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ snap install discord
snap "discord" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ snap help refresh
Usage:
snap refresh [refresh-OPTIONS] [...]

The refresh command updates the specified snaps, or all snaps in the system if
none are specified.

With no further options, the snaps are refreshed to the current revision of the
channel they're tracking, preserving their confinement options.

Revision choice via the --revision override requires the user to
have developer access to the snap, either directly or through the
store's collaboration feature, and to be logged in (see 'snap help login').

Note a later refresh will typically undo a revision override.

[refresh command options]
--color=[auto|never|always]     Use a little bit of color to highlight
some things. (default: auto)
--unicode=[auto|never|always]   Use a little bit of Unicode to improve
legibility. (default: auto)
--abs-time                      Display absolute times (in RFC 3339
format). Otherwise, display relative
times up to 60 days, then YYYY-MM-DD.
--no-wait                       Do not wait for the operation to finish
but just print the change id.
--channel=                      Use this channel instead of stable
--edge                          Install from the edge channel
--beta                          Install from the beta channel
--candidate                     Install from the candidate channel
--stable                        Install from the stable channel
--devmode                       Put snap in development mode and disable
security confinement
--jailmode                      Put snap in enforced confinement mode
--classic                       Put snap in classic mode and disable
security confinement
--amend                         Allow refresh attempt on snap unknown to
the store
--revision=                     Refresh to the given revision, to which
you must have developer access
--cohort=                       Refresh the snap into the given cohort
--leave-cohort                  Refresh the snap out of its cohort
--list                          Show the new versions of snaps that would
be updated with the next refresh
--time                          Show auto refresh information but do not
perform a refresh
--ignore-validation             Ignore validation by other snaps blocking
the refresh
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ aptitude search "?broken"
cougarxr7@gonespy:~/Desktop$ aptitude search "?broken"

Comment: You have to start `sudo apt-get check` and post any error output to the question. Then run `sudo apt-get install aptitude` followed by `aptitude search "?broken"` .

Comment: Please move last command output to the question body. Then execute `sudo apt-get update` and retry with  `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and `aptitude search "?broken"`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information about broken packages you have to execute one of the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get check`

  Its purpose is described in the `man apt-get` locally (or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)):

  > **`check`**
  > check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks for broken dependencies.
- `aptitude search "?broken"`

  its purpose is described in `/usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/ch02s04s05.html#searchBroken` locally:

  > Select packages that have a broken dependency.

To fix the broken packages you can start with `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`